# how to put an image onto a sprite pygame

Tags: python, class, pygame, sprite

I am creating a game like pacman in pygame using python. I want to assign a image of a jewel to the `jewel` class. In the maze 'J' Represents the `jewel`. So just to make it clear how would i assign an image to the Jewel Class so that all the J's in the maze map are that image?

The class for the jewel is

```
class Jewel(object):
    """Class to hold Jewel sprite properties"""

    def __init__(self, pos):
        jewels.append(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 16, 16)
```

The class for the wall and maze is

```
class Wall(object):
    """Class to hold Wall sprite properties"""

    def __init__(self, pos):
        walls.append(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 16, 16)

walls = [] #List to contain walls
jewels = []#List to contain Jewels

#!-----------------------Maze Layout----------------------!

#Table used to create the level, where W = wall
level = [
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"W       J               W          JJJ           W",
"W                       W     W                  W",
"W    WWWW   WWWWW   WWWWW     W      WWWWWWWWWW  W",
"W    W          W       W     W           W      W",
"W    W      JJJJ        W   WWWWWWW       W      W",
"W    W   WW                    W          W      W",
"W    W    W     WWWW           W          W      W",
"W    WWW  W     W  W           W  W   WWWWW      W",
"W         W                    W  W              W",
"WWWW      WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW                 W",
"W  W     WW                    W                 W",
"W       WW                     W WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"W             WWW              W                 W",
"W   WW               WW  WWW   W                 W",
"W    W  WWW          WWWWWWW   WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW  W",
"W    W    W   WWW       WW         W          W  W",
"W    WW   W                            W      W  W",
"W     W   W          WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW W  W",
"WWWW      WWWWW      WW  WWW                  W  W",
"W  W      W                W  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW  W",
"W  W   WWWW     W  W       W     W               W",
"W      W           W  WWW  W            W        W",
"W      WWWW        W  W    WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"W  WW     W   WWW  W  W      JJJ                 W",
"W   W     W        W  W                     J    W",
"W   W   WWW           W    WWW                   W",
"W  WWW       WWWWWWWWWW      WWWW                W",
"W    W       W                  WWWWWWW    W     W",
"WW   W    WWWW        WWWWWW          WWWW WWWW  W",
"WJ   W                   W            W    W     W",
"W     W  J    WWW           WWWWW    W    W  WWWW",
"WWW   W        W      W               W WWWW     W",
"W W       WWWWWW   WWWW               W    W     W",
"W WWW     W        W         WWWWW    WWWW WWWWW W",
"W       WWW        W     W               W       W",
"W       W                W               W       W",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
]

#Draw the wall rects as shown in the table above
x = y = 0
for row in level:
    for column in row:
        if column == "W":
            Wall((x, y))
        if column == "J":
            Jewel((x, y))
        x += 16
    y += 16
    x = 0

#Draw walls and jewels
    for wall in walls:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (WHITE), wall.rect)

    for jewel in jewels:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (BLUE), jewel.rect)
```

Comment: As an unrelated hint: if you keep you game maps in separated TXT files, you will have the exact same in memory structure after doing something like `level = line.strip() for line in open("levelfile.txt").readlines()` - as you have there, but this way, the `levelfile.txt` can be just plain text, without you worrying about quoting or putting a comma after each line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add the image as an attribute for your objects - 
for example, you can load them at the `__init__` method like:

```
def __init__(self, pos):
    walls.append(self)
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 16, 16)
    self.image = pygame.image.load("/path/to/image_file.png")
```

and then, on your game loop, instead of drawing a rect, call the 
`blit` method of the "screen" (which is a `pygame.Surface` object) passing the image:

```
for jewel in jewels:
    screen.blit(jewel.image, jewel.rect)
```

Later on when you have got a little more structure on the game, you should put your game objects in specialized sprite groups which can then make use of the `.image` and `.rect` attributes of the sprites to blit them to screen when the group `draw` method is called.
(check the docs on http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html), instead of calling `blit` directly.